# Generating Patterns in Pattern Lab

Tags: patternlab.io

I have managed to install and run the mustache version of Pattern Lab.

Now I wanted to install the thin version, I have used composer to install the thin version of Pattern Lan with the following command:

```
composer create-project pattern-lab/edition-thin my-project-name
```

It created the file and folder structure. I am now trying to generate patterns with the following:

```
php core/console --generate
```

But I get the following response:

```
    it doesn't appear that pattern lab has been set-up yet...
please install pattern lab's dependencies by typing: php core/bin/composer.phar install...
```

Even if I use the bundled version of Pattern Lab Thin Edition, there is no core > scripts folder and no installPatternLab.command file.

What am I missing?

brgds
-Sohail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i was getting the same trouble i try to clarify what is wrong with this aproach.

Generally it looks ( at least it looked for me ) like the Thin Edition is something you can use out of the box, but it is not.
Its just the absolute base on which you can build your own systems on top.

To get a complete working solution you need to define an Pattern-Engine and an Styleguide!

If you have none of them build yourself you need to go with some of the other Editions ( i have choosen Twig ) which will come bundled with the missing packages.